# Instagram deprecation affect user auth login?

Tags: instagram-api

Just got the email from Instagram api platform most of the api use is now disabled (effective immediately) with Public Content in 12/11/18 and Basic in early 2020 to be disabled.

At which phase will it affect apps using instagram login? like for example Tinder let's users login once to connect/share their Instagram photos.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly these changes will impact the commercial use of APIs, there is no restriction for self-data or using Oauth to authenticate other apps using Instagram.

Although apps asking for unnecessary permission asked to submit their Apss for further review, All the apps will be reviewed for their use.